# SQL Updating from an inner join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using microsoft Access.

If this query:

```
(SELECT FERMENT.FermentId
FROM FERMENT
INNER JOIN [BELGIUM BEER]
ON
FERMENT.FermentName = [BELGIUM BEER].FermentId ORDER BY [BELGIUM BEER].BeerId) a
```

returns FermentId, how do I update a different table with that column?

Example:

```
UPDATE EXAMPLETABLE
SET EXAMPLETABLE.FermentId = a.FermentId
FROM a
(SELECT FERMENT.FermentId
FROM FERMENT
INNER JOIN [BELGIUM BEER]
ON
FERMENT.FermentName = [BELGIUM BEER].FermentId ORDER BY [BELGIUM BEER].BeerId) a
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you need a relationship between `EXAMPLETABLE` and the thing you select from, than you could use something like `UPDATE EXAMPLETABLE
SET EXAMPLETABLE.FermentId = 
(SELECT FERMENT.FermentId
FROM FERMENT
INNER JOIN [BELGIUM BEER]
ON
FERMENT.FermentName = [BELGIUM BEER].FermentId WHERE EXAMPLETABLE.relationFieldName = [BELGIUM BEER].relationField ORDER BY [BELGIUM BEER].BeerId)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the sub-query returns more than one value, you need a second key to connect (JOIN) between the new values and the table you want to update (EXAMPLETABLE).

In this case I would try something like this:

```
UPDATE T 
SET    T.FERMENTID = A.FERMENTID 
FROM   EXAMPLETABLE AS T 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT FERMENT.FERMENTID, 
                          FERMENT.OTHERID 
                   FROM   FERMENT 
                          INNER JOIN [BELGIUM BEER] 
                                  ON FERMENT.FERMENTNAME = 
                                     [BELGIUM BEER].FERMENTID 
                   ORDER  BY [BELGIUM BEER].BEERID) AS A 
               ON A.OTHERID = T.OTHERID
```

If this isn't the case and the sub-query returns a single value, try something like this:

```
UPDATE EXAMPLETABLE 
SET    T.FERMENTID = (SELECT FERMENT.FERMENTID
                      FROM   FERMENT 
                             INNER JOIN [BELGIUM BEER] 
                                     ON FERMENT.FERMENTNAME = 
                                        [BELGIUM BEER].FERMENTID 
                      ORDER  BY [BELGIUM BEER].BEERID)
```

**Note that in this case you need to guarantee that the sub-query will never return more than one row!**

Comment: Lol, I just wrote that in a comment, in less words though. You got my vote!

Comment: Do you mean column or record with row?

Comment: Row! If the sub-query returns more than one row, SQL won't know which of the values to update the table with. :-)

Comment: the subquery returns 750 records, and exampletable contains 750 records. I basically want to update exampletable.FermentId with the 750 records from the subquery.

Comment: OK. Then use the first example and simply replace the OtherID field I used with the "key" that joins the 2 tables.

Comment: Thanks man, your query worked. I was having a hard time because I was joining the wrong tables :P

Answer (score 27):

Not sure what the relation of EXAMPLETABLE with your data is, but in general.

In Access the SET part is after the join, also skip the select part en the order by.
Should be something like this

```
UPDATE FERMENT
INNER JOIN ([BELGIUM BEER]  ON FERMENT.FermentName = [BELGIUM BEER].FermentId) 
SET EXAMPLETABLE.FermentColumn = a.FermentColumn
```

If it doent work try building the join in the query builder

Answer (score 13):

There is no need for defining a relationship between the two tables. Answer 10 (Arnoldiusss) is almost correct and by far the most comprehensible and shortest solution. And the fastest in execution. But the example code is wrong. The next code comes from one of my applications and runs fine in MS ACCESS 2013.

```
    UPDATE table1 T1 
    INNER JOIN table2 T2 
    ON T2.Id = T1.Id
    SET T1.myField = T2.myField;
```

For "the Belgian Beer Case" (I love that expression;-) it would be:

```
    UPDATE FERMENT AS T1
    INNER JOIN [BELGIUM BEER] AS T2 ON T1.FermentName = T2.FermentId 
    SET T1.FermentColumn1 = T2.FermentColumn1;
```