# Update a table according to subquery data

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have the following query that extracts unique records from a table:

```
SELECT First(t1.[Site Number]) AS [FirstOfSite Number], t1.[Customer Number], First(t1.Address1) AS FirstOfAddress1
FROM tblImport1 AS t1
GROUP BY t1.[Customer Number]
ORDER BY t1.[Customer Number];
```

I want to update a second table, say `tblimport`, according to the query above by linking the fields `t1.[Site Number]` with`tblimport.[Site Number]`.

I made the following query:

```
UPDATE tblimport 
INNER JOIN tblimport on  [tblimport].[site number]=[t1].[site number] 
  (SELECT First(t1.[Site Number]) AS [FirstOfSite Number], t1.[Customer Number], First(t1.Address1) AS FirstOfAddress1
  FROM tblImport1 AS t1
  GROUP BY t1.[Customer Number])
set tblimport.address1=t1.address1
```

However I get syntax error.  Where am I going wrong here?

**EDIT**

I read [the article suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882212/sql-updating-from-an-inner-join) and I have amended the query this way:

```
UPDATE D 
set D.address1=t1.address1
FROM tblimport as D
    INNER JOIN (SELECT First(t1.[Site Number]) AS [FirstOfSite Number], t1.[Customer Number], First(t1.Address1) AS FirstOfAddress1  FROM tblImport1 AS t1  GROUP BY t1.[Customer Number])
    ON t1.[Site Number]=D.[Site Number]
```

But I still have the syntax error.

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882212/sql-updating-from-an-inner-join) for the correct `UPDATE FROM` syntax. Your query is quite misformed: you inner join a table with iteself without giving each an alias. in the join condition you reference a table that only will be known later down the script. The sub select is just in the middle of nowhere, it should probably be placed where the second tblimport ist joined.

Comment: I have just amended the query accordingly but I still have the syntax error.

Comment: Try giving your select statement in the Inner Join an alias, use the alias in your ON statement and call the correct field in your SET: INNER JOIN (SELECT First(t1.[Site Number]) AS [FirstOfSite Number], t1.[Customer Number], First(t1.Address1) AS FirstOfAddress1  FROM tblImport1 AS t1  GROUP BY t1.[Customer Number]) AS Q
    ON Q.[Site Number]=D.[Site Number] - and in your set use: SET D.Address1 = Q.FirstOFAddress1