# SQL syntax for update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I have an update query in MS Access like this:

```
UPDATE ([tblDocument-VP] 
INNER JOIN [tbltransmittals-VP] ON [tblDocument-VP].OwnerDocumentNo = [tbltransmittals-VP].OwnerDocumentNo) 
INNER JOIN tblVendorName ON [tblDocument-VP].[Vendor Name] = tblVendorName.[VENDOR NAME] 
SET [tbltransmittals-VP].HyperDoc = [tblDocument-VP]![OwnerDocumentNo] + '-' + [tbltransmittals-VP].[REV] + '#' + [root]+[tblVendorName]![VendorDesc] + '\' + [tblDocument-VP]![Tag No] + '\' + [tblDocument-VP]![OwnerDocumentNo] + '-' + [REV] + '.pdf' + '#';
```

I would like to create a view of this in SQL Server, but when I try to do that, I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near '('"

I do not know what is problem, also i like to know can I use a view as a update query?

Comment: what do you mean with that you want to create a view of this in sql server ? An update cannot be in  a view. Do you want to do the same update in sql server or what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run a `UPDATE` inside a View.

A view can only be used to read/show data.

What you need is a [Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287545/how-do-i-make-a-stored-procedure-in-ms-access).

Also you have multiple syntax errors in your `UPDATE`-query.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882212/sql-updating-from-an-inner-join) a good explanation for updates with `INNER JOIN`'s

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on to GuidoG's comment, the SP should be like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspYourProcedureName  
AS
    UPDATE t2
    SET t2.HyperDoc = 
                t1.[OwnerDocumentNo] + '-' + 
                t2.[REV] + '#' + [root]+
                t3.[VendorDesc] + '\\' + t1.[Tag No] + '\\' + t1.[OwnerDocumentNo] + '-' + [REV] + '.pdf' + '#'
    FROM [tblDocument-VP]  t1
    INNER JOIN [tbltransmittals-VP] t2
            ON t1.OwnerDocumentNo = t2.OwnerDocumentNo 
    INNER JOIN tblVendorName t3
            ON t1.[Vendor Name] = t3.[VENDOR NAME] 
GO
```