# MS Access Update Query Keeps Asking for "Parameter Value"

Tags: sql, ms-access

I will try to simplify the situation as best as I can...
I work with a team of field service technicians.  We share a lot of our tools and equipment between us because SOMEONE doesnt want to spend money on us.  I am using MS Access to develope a way to track who has what tool or specific piece of equipment out of a pool of about 2000+ items.  I have got the process figured out down to one last step.  It gos like this:

1. Tech opens a form that shows current location/ownership of all 2000+ items, which is pulled off a SharePoint List and inserted into
   a local table.
2. Tech makes changes to local table.
3. When Tech is done, the Sharepoint List gets updated FROM the local table (This is where I am stuck).

I have followed every tutorial, walk through, and work around that I can understand.  But every time I run the Query, Access asks me for the "Parameter Value" of each field I am trying to update.  Mind you, everything I have found shows an example of how to update one field in a table.  I am trying to update 5 fields per row.  When I let Access build the SQL for this it looks like:

```
UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.[Asset ID] = Table2.[Asset ID] 
SET Table1.Department = Table2.[Department], Table1.[Cal Status] = Table2. 
[Cal Status], Table1.[Return Date] = Table2.[Return Date], Table1.Comments = 
Table2.[Comments], Table1.[Cal Due] = Table2.[Cal Due], Table1.Active = 
Table2.[Active];
```

The fields are not misspelled, I already checked and double checked that.

I have seen some comments about how Access has problems with UPDATE. But I am self taught with everything I do and I cant switch to something else until I understand this.  I just started with Access and SQL at the begining of this week, so please be patient with me.

**EDIT**

```
UPDATE Assets
SET Assets.Department = AssetsSharePoint.[Department],
Assets.[Cal Status]   = AssetsSharePoint.[Cal Status],
Assets.[Return Date]  = AssetsSharePoint.[Return Date],
Assets.Comments       = AssetsSharePoint.[Comments],
Assets.[Cal Due]      = AssetsSharePoint.[Cal Due],
Assets.Active         = AssetsSharePoint.[Active]
FROM Assets
INNER JOIN AssetsSharePoint ON Assets.[Asset ID] = AssetsSharePoint.[Asset 
ID];
```

This gives me a "Syntax Error.  Missing Operator"  Then Highlights `FROM`

**EDIT 2**

If I cut it down to 1 field, leave out the `FROM`, and include `WHERE` it works. I dont want to make 5 seperate queries for this.  But I guess I am going to have to....

Comment: I was also going to suggest updating a single field, but that sort of defeats the purpose of what you are trying to do.

Comment: This should work, especially if you created the query in the query designer. Maybe you have simplified the code too much, can you add the original query that isn't working?

Comment: @andre The code in the first edit is straight copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is off, and it should be `UPDATE ... SET ... FROM`:

```
UPDATE t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.[Asset ID] = t2.[Asset ID]
SET
    t1.Department    = t2.[Department],
    t1.[Cal Status]  = t2.[Cal Status],
    t1.[Return Date] = t2.[Return Date],
    t1.Comments      = t2.[Comments],
    t1.[Cal Due]     = t2.[Cal Due],
    t1.Active        = t2.[Active]
```

Comment: Thank you, I didnt expect such a quick answer!  I used that syntax (substituted the real table names) and it is giving me `Syntax error. Missing Operator in Query Expression` Then highlights `FROM`  And sorry I realize after seeing your response I could have tried a little harder to format my code.

Comment: @TuckerBlack I can't see the actual code you ran, so I can't explain why it didn't work.  [From this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882212/sql-updating-from-an-inner-join) my syntax looks correct.  Can you give me more information which would help me to debug your query?

Comment: Updated my original post with the info

Comment: @TuckerBlack One of our queries should be working.  Maybe someone else can shed light on this.

Comment: This is T-Sql, Access Sql doesn't do `UPDATE .. SET ... FROM ...`, see the 2nd answer in the question you linked.

Comment: @Andre I'm flying blind to be honest, because I don't have Access setup locally, so I can't test my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Assets, AssetsSharePoint
SET Assets.Department = AssetsSharePoint.[Department],
Assets.[Cal Status]   = AssetsSharePoint.[Cal Status],
Assets.[Return Date]  = AssetsSharePoint.[Return Date],
Assets.Comments       = AssetsSharePoint.[Comments],
Assets.[Cal Due]      = AssetsSharePoint.[Cal Due],
Assets.Active         = AssetsSharePoint.[Active]
WHERE Assets.[Asset ID] = AssetsSharePoint.[Asset ID];
```

Neater statement:

```
UPDATE Assets INNER JOIN AssetsSharePoint ON Assets.[Asset ID] = AssetsSharePoint.[Asset ID]
SET Assets.Department = AssetsSharePoint.[Department],
Assets.[Cal Status]   = AssetsSharePoint.[Cal Status],
Assets.[Return Date]  = AssetsSharePoint.[Return Date],
Assets.Comments       = AssetsSharePoint.[Comments],
Assets.[Cal Due]      = AssetsSharePoint.[Cal Due],
Assets.Active         = AssetsSharePoint.[Active]
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't working either.  It doesnt like the `FROM` statement

Comment: Oops, forgot to remove the FROM clause. Try again.

Comment: Sorry still no luck.

Comment: Forgot to adjust the WHERE clause, try again.

Comment: Nothing seems to work right, I am scrapping the idea and rethinking my approach.  Thank you for your help though.